# Read part of request from file like environment variable in Postman

Tags: postman

I'd like to do a Post request in Postman where part of the JSON request body is pulled from a file like if it was an environment variable.

So something like this:

```
{
    "field1": "value",
    "field2": "{{ENV_VAR}}"
}
```

But instead of `ENV_VAR` being an actual Postman variable it's the contents of a file. Specifically an escaped XML file.

My main end goal is to be able to send an XML string as the value of one of the request body properties but I don't want to have to rebuild the escaped XML string and copy it to Postman every time I change the content of the XML file I want to send.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/798

https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/7210

THis feature is not supported as of now.

The only thing you can do is to copy the content to environment varaible

you can copy content to environment variable from script as:

```
 let xml = "<yourxml>"
 pm.environment.set("ENV_VAR",xml)
```

you can pass content through -e flag if using newman